# List of tuples of arbitrary length to nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a list of tuples of the form:

```
my_list=[('a','aa','aaa',0),('a','aa','aab',1),('a','ab','aba',2)]
```

And I need it to convert it to a nested dictionary:

```
out={'a':{'aa':{'aaa':0,'aab':1},'ab':{'aba':2}}}
```

The crucial piece of my setting is that I **do not know** in advance the length of the tuples in my_list (4 is just an example). Is there an easy way to *generalize* the cases I saw in other answers (e.g. [Python list of tuples to nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224934/python-list-of-tuples-to-nested-dict) or [Convert a list of variable length Tuples into Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586310/convert-a-list-of-variable-length-tuples-into-dictionary)) beyond the fixed 3-element tuples they use?

I made various attempts with recursive functions but I do not have anything close to a solution.

Comment: An answer I've written previously does what you want. I'd say this question is close enough to that one to be a duplicate, but I can't mark it as such because that question doesn't have any accepted or upvoted answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73374876/843953 You don't need recursion, you just need to "drill down" into your dictionaries. Assign `out = {}`, then keep calling `assign_nested_dict(out, tpl)` for each `tpl` in your list

Comment: @Thana It might be worth the effort to implement a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Also, my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74058582/2476977) comes to mind

Comment: @Thana Should the last tuple be `('a','ab','aba',2)` instead?

Comment: @BenGrossmann definitely more elegant, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the first keys, setting aside the last pair of items which will be a key-value pair, and set dictionaries in-between (using `setdefault` here, but you could do that part manually):

```
result = {}
for *keys, last_key, value in my_list:
    current = result
    for key in keys:
        current = current.setdefault(key, {})
    current[last_key] = value
```

Just to be explicit by what I mean by "manually" (I guess I should rather say "explicitly"):

```
result = {}
for *keys, last_key, value in my_list:
    current = result
    for key in keys:
        if key not in current:
            current[key] = {}
        current = current[key]
    current[last_key] = value
```